# matplotlib - control capstyle of line collection/large number of lines

Tags: python, matplotlib, line

Similarly to a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11312579/networkx-draw-networkx-edges-capstyle) of mine, I'd like to control the capstyle of lines being drawn using matplotlib. However, I have an extremely large number of lines, and drawing with anything other than a line collection takes way too long. Are there any workarounds to control the capstyle of lines in a line collection in a generic way (or alternatively, super fast ways of drawing a large number of `Line2D` lines). For instance, I've tried using the matplotlib rc settings via:

```
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.rcParams['lines.solid_capstyle'] = 'round'
mpl.rcParams['lines.solid_joinstyle'] = 'round'
```

But this doesn't appear to have any effect. From the docstring for `collections.py`:

> The classes are not meant to be as flexible as their single element counterparts (e.g. you may not be able to select all line styles) but they are meant to be fast for common use cases (e.g. a large set of solid line segemnts)

Which explains *why* I can't seem to control various parameters, but I still want to do it! I've had a look at the code for the AGG backend (`_backend_agg.cpp`: not that I really understand it), and it appears that line_cap and line_join are controlled by `gc.cap` and `gc.join`, where gc comes from the `GCAgg` class. Does anyone know how one can control this from Python? Am I asking the right question here? Perhaps that are easier ways to control these parameters?

Any help is greatly appreciated... I'm desperate to get this working, so even crazy hacks are welcome!

Thanks,

Carson

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you mention in your question that you don't mind "dirty" solutions, one option would as follows.

The "drawing process" of a particular `LineCollection` is handled by the `draw` method defined in the `Collection` class (the base of `LineCollection`). This method creates an instance of `GraphicsContextBase` (defined in `backend_bases.py`) via the statement `gc = renderer.new_gc()`. It seems to be exactly this object which governs among other things the properties controlling the `capstyle` (property `_capstyle`). Therefore, one could subclass `GraphicsContextBase`, override the `_capstyle` property, and inject a new `new_gc` method into the `RendererBase` class so that consequent calls to `new_gc` return the customized instance:

Borrowing the example from the answer by @florisvb (assuming Python3):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import types

import numpy as np
from matplotlib.backend_bases import GraphicsContextBase, RendererBase
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.collections import LineCollection

class GC(GraphicsContextBase):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self._capstyle = 'round'

def custom_new_gc(self):
    return GC()

RendererBase.new_gc = types.MethodType(custom_new_gc, RendererBase)
#----------------------------------------------------------------------
np.random.seed(42)

x = np.random.random(10)
y = np.random.random(10)

points = np.array([x, y]).T.reshape((-1, 1, 2))
segments = np.concatenate([points[:-1], points[1:]], axis=1)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

linewidth = 10
lc = LineCollection(segments, linewidths=linewidth)
ax.add_collection(lc)

fig.savefig('fig.png')
```

This produces:
[image]

Comment: Nice. That looks gorgeous! Thanks @ewcz!

Comment: @ewcz This solution works great for agg based output, thanks! I've been looking through the source for other backends because I'd like to get this effect in a pdf too. I can't seem to get the 'ps' or the 'pdf' backends to accept the patch that you've written, but interestingly the 'svg' backend can handle it. Any thoughts on how to tweak this patch for pdf output?

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but export to pdf does not work, I used this answer to make it work https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49983192/how-to-plot-and-export-multi-colored-line-with-smooth-edges?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: You can achieve a similar result without having to create a custom subclass, by calling `set_capstyle` on your collection. For example, I had a contour plot (created with `tricontour`) that had this issue. This bit of code fixed the `capstyle`, and gave a cleaner plot:

    `cont = ax.tricontour(..<custom stuff here>..)`  

    `for coll in cont.collections:`  

    `coll.set_capstyle('round')`

Answer (score 9):

To update the answer from @ewcz as this thread still comes up in search results.
One can now use `path_effects` instead of defining their own GraphicsContextBase.

e.g.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.patheffects as path_effects
from matplotlib.collections import LineCollection

np.random.seed(42)

x = np.random.random(10)
y = np.random.random(10)

points = np.array([x, y]).T.reshape((-1, 1, 2))
segments = np.concatenate([points[:-1], points[1:]], axis=1)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

linewidth = 10

### Stroke redraws the segment passing kwargs down to the GC renderer
lc = LineCollection(segments, linewidths=linewidth, 
    path_effects=[path_effects.Stroke(capstyle="round")])

ax.add_collection(lc)

fig.show()
```

[Example png output with smooth lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TKLs2.png)
and it also seems to work well with pdf output

Answer (score 1):

I was struggling with the same issue. I ended up plotting a scatter plot on top of my line collection. It's not perfect, but it may work for your application. There's a few subtleties - below is a working example.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.collections import LineCollection

x = np.random.random(10)
y = np.random.random(10)
z = np.arange(0,10)

points = np.array([x, y]).T.reshape(-1, 1, 2)
segments = np.concatenate([points[:-1], points[1:]], axis=1)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

linewidth = 10
cmap = plt.get_cmap('jet')
norm = plt.Normalize(np.min(z), np.max(z))
color = cmap(norm(z))

lc = LineCollection(segments, linewidths=linewidth, cmap=cmap, norm=norm)
lc.set_array(z)
lc.set_zorder(z.tolist())
ax.add_collection(lc)

ax.scatter(x,y,color=color,s=linewidth**2,edgecolor='none', zorder=(z+2).tolist())
```