# How to plot and export multi-colored line with smooth edges

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I tried to plot a single line with multiple colors and for that I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17240694/python-how-to-plot-one-line-in-different-colors) example.

Exported pdf result has breaks at the starts and the ends of the lines, while I would like the result to a smooth line without breaks.
LineCollection plots every single line in one color, but I am also fine with smoothly changing colors. 
[image: lines with multiple coulors]

I tried to add [round ends](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11578760/matplotlib-control-capstyle-of-line-collection-large-number-of-lines) for each line, but it does not affect the exported pdf result (while plt.show() plot looks nicer and with round edges in place).

Code for reference:

```
lc = mcoll.LineCollection(segments, array=z, cmap='copper', linewidth=3)
ax.add_collection(lc)
plt.savefig("{}_l.pdf".format(filenamebase))
```

Comment: You could use more points such that the curve appears smoother. In the simplest case one can just double the number of points, as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47856091/4124317).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem has gone when I used svg format and then converted the plot with inkscape. Though the original problem remains, and apperently there is something wrong with savefig for pdf, but svg->pdf trick avoids the problem and makes the round edges of the lines.

The script below implements the trick (and also produces pdf + tex files for a convenient embedding into an article).

```
def export_plot(filenamebase, export_area_drawing = True, export_latex = True):

  plt.savefig("{}_l.pdf".format(filenamebase))

  if export_latex:
    ead = ''
    if export_area_drawing:
      ead = '--export-area-drawing'

    el = '--export-latex'
    plt.savefig("{}.svg".format(filenamebase))
    cmd = ''' env -u LD_LIBRARY_PATH inkscape -T -f {0}.svg \
              --export-background-opacity=0 \
              {1} {2} --export-pdf={0}.pdf'''.format(filenamebase, ead, el)
    os.system(cmd)
    os.system('rm {}.svg'.format(filenamebase))
```

Comment: Thanks, had the same problem, but I used cairosvg library on windows. Note that I still had an issue, solved by an answer (not the accepted one) in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33812902/pycharm-cannot-find-library